# Short Description is not saving in magento 2

Tags: product, magento-2.1, admin-panel, adminform

Short description is not saving in version 2.1.3. I tried with in modes: developer, production and with **enable/disabled** cache.

Searched through **forum/blogs** and it seems M2 bug. Please correct me if I am wrong. Looking for valuable suggestions from community.

Comment: Do you mean you do not see it changed in backend or you do not see it updated in frontend?

Comment: it seems store issue, change store view and then check or check manually in db. you can find the bug or?

Comment: Its not working by changing store view. I have single store so that should not be issues.
@Phoenix128_RiccardoT ..its not saving in admin and stuck there, not even displaying success message. I require to  adding HTML content.

Comment: Check in your Javascript console to see if you have any error. Also try disabling wysiwyg.

Comment: Thanks all for your responses. This issue was from Nexcess Server and its sorted out now.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was from Nexcess Server and its sorted out now. Nexcess server create many issues from posting data to update product data.

It become very problematic even fresh magento was not working as expected. Mode Security is one reason of Nexcess that create lot of problems.

If any have such issues then its recommended to test on local and Devbox is great alternative for local setup.